# Lookups in Long range Values

Tags: java

I have Long value to be looked upon in Lookup values and return the corresponds value. For the sake of not getting any value related errors I have set up all values to Long type.

Here is my code

```
package RestClient;

public class Range {

    public static Long upper;
    public static Long value;

    public Range(Long i, Long j) {
        Range.upper = i;
        Range.value = j;
    }

}



package RestClient;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Rangelookup {

    public static String Lookup(Long key) {

        NavigableMap<Long, Range> map = new TreeMap<Long, Range>();
        map.put(5045076263000000000L, new Range(5045076263249899999L, 507866L));
        map.put(5045076263249900000L, new Range(5045076263249999999L, 507866L));
        map.put(5045076263250000000L, new Range(5045076263499899999L, 507868L));
        map.put(5045076263499900000L, new Range(5045076263499999999L, 507868L));
        map.put(5045076263500000000L, new Range(5045076263749899999L, 507867L));
        map.put(5045076263749900000L, new Range(5045076263749999999L, 507867L));
        map.put(5045076263750000000L, new Range(5045076263999899999L, 507869L));
        map.put(5045076263999900000L, new Range(5045076263999999999L, 507869L));
        map.put(5045075892250000000L, new Range(5045075892499899999L, 507867L));
        map.put(5045075892499900000L, new Range(5045075892499999999L, 507867L));
        map.put(5045075892000000000L, new Range(5045075892249899999L, 507869L));
        map.put(5045075892249900000L, new Range(5045075892249999999L, 507869L));

        String output = "";
        Map.Entry<Long, Range> entry = map.floorEntry(key);
        if (entry == null) {

            output = "No Entry Found";

        } else if (key <= entry.getValue().upper) {

            output = entry.getValue().value.toString();

        } else {

            output = "No Entry Found";

        }

        System.out.println(output);
        return output;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Lookup(5045076263249899985L);

    }

}
```

May I know please why its not returning any value ? Why its going to "no Entry found" case ?

May I Know please what am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The entry that is found is this one:

```
map.put(5045076263000000000L, new Range(5045076263249899999L, 507866L));
```

But the upper value `5045075892249999999` is less than the lookup key `5045076263249899985`:

```
5045075892249999999
      <
5045076263249899985
```

Therefore you get `"No Entry Found"`.